# Twig template variables short code not displaying

Tags: html, twig, symfony4

I've configured in my home controller, properties.
Now when I try to display my values using twig templates shortcodes, nothing is displayed. Any help?

I've configured in my home controller, properties:

```
    public function index(PropertiesRepository $repository): Response {

    $properties = $repository->findLatest();
    // No longer necessary to use this method since we now use the AbstractController
    // return new Response($this->twig->render('pages/home.html.twig'));

    return $this->render('pages/home.html.twig', [
        'properties' => $properties
    ]);

}
```

Here's my twig template code, notice that I've already tried the raw filter but without any success:

```
    <div class="row">
        {% for property in properties %}
            <div class="col-3">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title"><a href="">{{ property.title | raw }}</a></h5>
                        {{ property.bedrooms | raw }}
                        <p class="card-text">{{ property.city | raw }} ({{ property.postalCode | raw }})</p>
                        <div class="text-primary">{{ property.formatedPrice | raw }} €</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

Comment: Did u try to `{{ dump(property) }}` to verify the attributes are present?

Comment: I would dump `$properties` from the controller first to make sure you are getting any results there. If that works, then use `{{ dump(properties) }}` in your template to see how they are coming across. My guess is that your problem is back in the controller; the template looks correct.